# @ServerTimestamp is allways null on Firebase Firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Here is My Model class:

```
import com.google.firebase.firestore.ServerTimestamp;
import java.util.Date;

        public class YourModelClass {
            private @ServerTimestamp Date timestamp;

            YourModelClass() {}

            public Date getTimestamp() {
                return timestamp;
            }

            public void setTimestamp(Date timestamp) {
                this.timestamp = timestamp;
            }

            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return "YourModelClass{" +
                        "timestamp=" + timestamp +
                        '}';
            }
        }
```

I am getting null while i am printing in Log

```
    Logger.info("Date", new YourModelClass()+"------"+new YourModelClass().getTimestamp() + "");
```

This is the error:

```
Output: 02-22 18:33:12.066 18980-18980/com.spendeye I/Date: YourModelClass{timestamp=null}------null
```

Please let me know the solution guys.

Comment: canyou post the code you use to upload the servertime to firebase ? and also, in your firebase database, the names are the same as your POJO ? Thats very important

Answer (score 0):

That's not the correct way of retrieving the date from your database. Assuming that you are using a `get()` call, when retrieving the `date` as an object of type `Date` class, you need to use the following code:

```
Date date = yourModelClass.getDate();
DateFormat dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM, Locale.US); //Or any other locale
String creationDate = dateFormat.format(date);
Log.d("TAG", creationDate);
```

As you can see, I'm using the formated date that I get from the database, I'm not creating a new instance of a class. You can see this approach also in one of my **[tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLn2n4GESV0AmXOWOam729bC47v0d0Ohee)** in which I have explained step by step how can you add and display the date.

Answer (score 0):

If you are printing the log before it is being stored on the Firestore, then the value of attribute `timestamp` with `@ServerTimestamp` in any class before it is saved on Firestore is always going to be null.

Hence you are getting **null**.

If you **could remove the log statement** and let the object get saved on Firestore then the log statement would be different, not showing null, when you are fetching that class object back from Firestore.